# UpdateLayeredWindow() and the OpenGL context

Tags: c++, c, winapi, opengl

I want to use UpdateLayeredWindow for a Win32 window that will be drawn with OpenGL. It seems that I have to create the context to a bitmap ( I will then pass this bitmap to UpdateLayeredWindow() ) unstead of to a window. But do I still need the double buffer flag ( at the context creation with wgl ) ? as the bitmap is a buffer.

Also what is the effect of the WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP ? If it just prevents the creation of the 2 nd buffer there are two cases :

- OpenGL double buffer + WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP = 2 buffers
- OpenGL single buffer + i dont use the flag = 2 buffers

In both case there are 2 buffers. What is the best ?

Comment: There really should be some practical effort at coding before posting this question. I see you are using phrases like _It seems that I have to_, instead of phrases like _This is what I've observed when I tried..._  Please show your work thus far, point to exactly what the problem is, and it would be best if the code you show is in the form of a [mcve].  For now I have to vote to close for the reason [that this question is off-topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question needs to provide evidence of actual attempt, and more specificity about what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know what i have to do tha'ts why I'm asking I did lost of test and read the docs but i don't know how does updatelayeredwindows works i can't give more informations. please just anser. Also if what i do works it does not means it's a good way of doing it

Comment: A series of well stated Google queries will yield the answers you need to the questions you've asked here.  That's what I do on the occasion that I am doing something new to me.  This site is really for targeted problems encountered when actually running into buggy software behavior, failure to compile, questions about things that are in the process of being built, etc.  You are still in the learning phase.  i.e. you have not written anything (or posted anything) yet.  I cannot help to solve a problem that does not yet exist.

Comment: I've only been doing this for 3 days

Comment: Then you've more reading and studying to do before your ready to code. And coding something is a prerequisite for using this site  Look for some OpenGL tutorials.

Comment: ...[such as this link](https://www.prasannavl.com/2016/10/introducing-winapi-graphics-with-direct3d-d2d1-gdi-opengl-and-skia/)

Comment: I know how OpenGL works i don't know how win32 works. I just want an anser : yes or no.

Comment: If you're looking to evaluate performance then there's only one way to know for sure: Try it both ways and compare. You said don't know how does `updatelayeredwindows` works, please see [How to use LayeredWindows properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10449503/11128312) and [Draw HBITMAP onto layered window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627383/11128312)

Comment: nothing related to the question so far...